# Как в htaccess добавить к url свою надпись?

Tags: регулярные-выражения, .htaccess, apache

Подскажите плиз как изменить 
http://site.net/log-out/ 
на 
http://site.net/log-out/index.html

То есть нужно чтобы на каждой странице добавлялось окончание "/index.html".

Пример кода.

```
RewriteRule ([^/]+)/([^/]+) $1$2/index.html
RewriteRule ^(.*) $1/index.html
```

Comment: Обычно люди добиваются обратного эффекта, убирая индексный файл...

Comment: Да, но я не могу именно добавить)

Comment: Приведите код, которым вы пытаетесь решить задачу.

Comment: Не надо писать примеры кода в комментариях.

Comment: @ArtemisFaul, смело редактируйте вопрос для добавления любых уточнений

Comment: Попробуйте добавить такую директиву `RedirectMatch "(.*)" "http://site.net$1/index.html"`

Comment: @mymedia, попробовал, вот что получилось: `http://site.net/index.html/index.html/index.html/index.html/index.html/index.html/index.html/index.html/index.html/index.html/index.html/index.html/index.html/index.html/index.html/index.html/index.html/index.html/index.html/index.html/index.html`

Comment: Эм… ок. Небольшое переполение)))

Comment: Ваша затея не имеет смысла особенно если ваш проект на Joomla

Comment: @Дмитрий Гвоздь, имеет смысл, старый проект имеет такую структуру url, если я не сделаю как было, то все странички выпадут из индекса.

Comment: Для таких вещей делается переадресация всех старых станиц на новые через 301 редирект.

Comment: Сайты построены внутри каталогов на веб-сервере, каждая веб-страницы  в виде отдельного файла. Иногда, не существует ни одного файла, перечисленных в адресе. Например: http://example.com/ . Должен быть еще файл, с которого браузер имеет что-то для отображения. Этот файл является страницей по умолчанию для этого каталога. На большинстве веб-серверов по умолчанию страница в каталоге называется index.html. Этот файл возвращает сервер при запросе доменного имени. Таким образом добавляя  index для каждой страницы вы запутаете ваш сервер и он будет возвращать ошибку 500 (скорее всего).

Answer (score 2):

В Joomla 3.x (как в прочем и в более ранних версиях) есть встроенные настройки SEO оптимизации сайта. Чтобы открыть и редактировать данные настройки, нужно перейти в главном меню: Меню «Система» => общие настройки = вкладка сайт (опция Настройки SEO).

[image: админ-панель]

**Добавление HTML суффикса к URL**

Добавляет в конце всех ссылок суффикс *.html

Если стоит ДА, то ссылка будет выглядеть так:

```
http://joomfans.com/articles/joomla-seo.html
```

Если стоит нет - то так:

```
http://joomfans.com/articles/joomla-seo
```

[Подробнее о настройках SEO адресов для Joomla](http://joomfans.com/blogs/vstroennye-nastrojki-seo-optimizatsii-joomla-3x.html)

Comment: Спасибо, это всё я испльзую, но я не могу сделать чтобы в конце url добавлялось окончание "index.html". Результат `http://joomfans.com/articles/joomla-seo/index.html http://joomfans.com/contact/index.html http://joomfans.com/about/index.html`

Comment: Штатными средствами этого не сделать. Используйте дополнительные компоненты, например https://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/site-management/sef/joomsef/

Comment: Только непонятно, зачем вам требуется все это :) Практического смысла тут никакого нет.

Comment: нужно узнать как добавлять в конец url что-нибудь - хотябы поэтому))

Comment: Так Joomla и так в конец html добавляет, этого достаточно.

Comment: мне нужно своими ручками)) именно "/index.html" на все страницы

Answer (score 1):

Редирект URL, которые не кончаются на точку, за которой следует 3 или 4 цифробуквенных символа.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{3,4}
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html
```

Для более тонкой настройки: белый список расширений, к которым не надо добавлять .html, например:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(html|css|js|less|jpg|png|gif)$
```

Но если вы используете, к примеру, Wordpress, то это все настраивается внутри движка, поскольку CMS соответственным образом формирует внутренние ссылки.

Comment: В том то и беда, что использую джумлу, точней изучаю(.

Comment: Тогда придется отдельный ответ для Joomla написать.

Comment: А вам - точнее сформулировать вопрос, хотя бы заголовок, поскольку ответ зависит от используемой CMS.

Answer (score 1):

Не проверял, но можете попробовать...

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /$1 [L]
```

Comment: в этом случае и css, и картинки, все файлы тоже получат расширение .html

Comment: Ну да, можно же добавить исключения, как в вашем примере)

Comment: @Vadim Pedchenko, попробовал, не сработало

Comment: @Artemis Faul, Так в Joomla уже всё и так есть...

Comment: @Vadim Pedchenko, там есть чтобы я могу получить ко всем стариницам дополнительное окончание в url ?))

Comment: @ArtemisFaul, Вам же labris, даже скрин предоставил! Не пойму чего вам ещё нужно!?

Comment: @ArtemisFaul, А если Вы хотите к каждому url, добавить index.html, тогда я немогу понять ЗАЧЕМ??? Ведь это глупо и не красиво, есть адрес: site.ru/category/article, а Вы хотите: site.ru/category/article/index.html ??????????

Comment: @Vadim Pedchenko, сателиты делаю, мне нужет конкретный url!