# "CMS Joomla" Как в htaccess добавить к url свою надпись?

Tags: регулярные-выражения, .htaccess, apache, joomla, joomla3

Подскажите как изменить `http://site.net/log-out.html` на `http://site.net/log-out/index.html`

Поконкретней: не могу сделать чтобы в конце url добавлялось окончание "index.html".

`http://site.net/category/material/index.html 
http://site.net/contact/index.html 
http://site.net/about/index.html
и т.д.`

Пример моего htaccess:

```
`## No directory listings
 IndexIgnore *

## Can be commented out if causes errors, see notes above.
Options +FollowSymlinks
Options -Indexes

## Mod_rewrite in use.

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{3,4}
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1/index.html

# Block any script trying to base64_encode data within the URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode[^(]*\([^)]*\) [OR]
# Block any script that includes a <script> tag in URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|%3C)([^s]*s)+cript.*(>|%3E) [NC,OR]
# Block any script trying to set a PHP GLOBALS variable via URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
# Block any script trying to modify a _REQUEST variable via URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})
# Return 403 Forbidden header and show the content of the root home page
RewriteRule .* index.php [F]



# RewriteBase /

## Begin - Joomla! core SEF Section.
#
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
#
# If the requested path and file is not /index.php and the request
# has not already been internally rewritten to the index.php script
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
# and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical folder
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# internally rewrite the request to the index.php script
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]`
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как в htaccess добавить к url свою надпись?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/638323/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2-htaccess-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba-url-%d1%81%d0%b2%d0%be%d1%8e-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%8c)

Comment: @ArtemisFaul, вам нужно реализовать это средствами apache или joomla?

Comment: Artemis - такими методами извращения вы на 100% и гарантированно испортите SEO результаты вашего сайта в поисковиках !! нет необходимости для каждой ссылки вставлять index.html... если просто хотите использовать префикс .html  настройте в конфигурации Добавление HTML суффикса к URL

Comment: @Arsen, Это я всё знаю спасибо, вот только не могу добавить в конец url "index.html" ((.

Comment: а скажите зачем вы хотите ко всем ссылкам добавить index.html ? что вы хотите получить в итоге? что это даст вашему Joomla сайту?

Comment: @Arsen, на старом сайте была такая структура, если я напишу другую, то все старинички выпадут из индексации.

Comment: Для решения такой проблемы вам не надо добавлять index.html  к новым ссылкам, а лучше всего наоборот, на новом сайте через htaccess сделать 301 редирект всех ссылок которые заканчиваются на index.html  т.е
старая ссылка  http://vashsite.ru/contact/index.html
новая  ссылка  http://vashsite.ru/contact/

Comment: @Arsen, нет, есть только 1 сайт, редирект не подходит.